# Preventing array to go out of bounds when passed a method parameter

Tags: c, arrays, memory

First thing first. I am aware that there is no way direct way to find out size of an incoming array in a method as they are received as pointers. Situation I am facing is something similar but different in nature.

I have a method something like this:

```
void method( int no_of_elements, int arr[])
{
   /* checking if array has 'no_of_elements' of elements.
}
```

I want to check if the integer array `arr[]` has `no_of_elements` or not. Based on this my method shall process further. I know it almost sounds like finding the size of `arr[]`. At-least that's the only way I could think to check my requirement. Any approach to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: `int arrEleCount = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);` This will get element count of array `arr`.

Comment: @EricWang Not within the function

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Ok, then I don't understand what OP want to do, what's difference where to check? I think there are 2 solution: 1) In the function which calls the target function, use a `if()` to test the formula, so that decide whether call the function. 2) Move the `if()` into target function, and wrap all logic inside it.

Comment: @EricWang The parameter `arr` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: @EricWang Please come up with a concrete working example. Start [here](http://ideone.com/ctdJjm) and modify as you see fit.

Comment: @zenith Yeah, you are right, can't test inside function, only outside function, before call the target method where the array is declare. Or, declare array as static global.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, zenith is right, I modified the code to use static global array at http://ideone.com/2xqbcv, if that's acceptable to op.

Comment: @EricWang We'll see but I somehow have my doubts.

Comment: 'I know it almost sounds like finding the size of arr[]' - it sounds EXACTLY like that:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Situation I am facing is something similar but different in nature.

No, it is the very same thing. You can't know how large the pointed-at chunk of data is, unless that information is provided, period.

---

Related, you can force an array to be of a certain size:

```
void method( int no_of_elements, int arr[no_of_elements])
```

or you can force it to be *at least* of a certain size:

```
void method( int no_of_elements, int arr[static no_of_elements])
```

None of these will likely yield compiler errors/warnings though, since arrays "decay" into pointers to first element when passed to functions. The above are rather to be regarded as documentation, a contract you sign with the caller. If they violate the contract by passing something else, it is their fault.

But very good compilers, or external static analyser tools, may be able to spot type-related bugs if you use these methods. If you just use a `int*`, they won't.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to check if the integer array arr[] has "no_of_elements' or
>   not. Based on this my method shall process further.

This is not possible, the caller must pass the size of the array to this function for example as additional parameter.